# Shared microsoft exchange calendars

Tags: calendar, exchange, outlook

I'm trying to add shared a calendar shared with me through outlook, but I only get my calendar and not the one that a colleague has shared with me. How can I view their calendars in the native calendar app?

<sub>Nexus 5, KitKat</sub>